# Yii - How to get a values array from an Active Record

Tags: arrays, activerecord, yii

Using Yii, how can I get an array from an Active Record.

Say something like this:

`array('foo', 'bar', 'lala')`

From something like this:

```
MyTable::model()->findall()
```

Comment: what are foo, bar and lala? attributes of a table/model or different model objects?

Comment: are you trying to ask how could you use condition, params etc for findAll function ?

Comment: Values. I want to get an array o values from a table. For example an array of countries out of a table which contains countries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use **ActiveRecord**. Use `CDBCommand->queryColumn()`

Comment: Meh... Django has this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list Why can't Yii have that too ?

Comment: If you're using any beforeFind or afterFind methods for your ActiveRecord, this will (obviously) not call them. For example, I was doing some prefiltering in a beforeFind that wasn't called in queryColumn, so we were getting more results than expected. Luckily we had some tests in place to catch things like this, otherwise this would have hurt us down the road in production.

Comment: the question is about getting actual data out of MyTable::model()->findall(); So, the answer is irrelevent

Comment: Answer is off-topic. OP asks about converting result of ActiveRecord into an array. Not about querying data from database in form of array.

Answer (score 25):

If i understand you correctly:

```
$users = User::model()->findAll();
$usersArr = CHtml::listData( $users, 'id' , 'name');
print_r( $usersArr );
```

It will give you array id => name

```
Array {
    2 => 'someone',
    20 => 'kitty',
    102 => 'Marian',
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that, but isn't there a way to use just the 'name' ?

Comment: The key should not be a problem if you only want to use the name? You can use array_values to reset the keys if you want.

Comment: My God! CHtml to get as array! MacGyver!

Answer (score 9):

For yii2 , use:

```
yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(MyModel::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'));
```

or

```
yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::getColumn(MyModel::find()->all(), 'name'));
```

Answer (score 7):

**ActiveRecord** class has an attribute called *attributes*. You can find its description here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#attributes-detail.

In order to get all attributes in an array, use this: `$var = $model->attributes;`

Answer (score 3):

You could also do something like

```
$countries = Country::model()->findAll();
array_values(CHtml::listData($countries, 'country_id', 'country_name'));
```

which returns an array of all country names, or

```
array_keys(CHtml::listData($countries, 'country_id', 'country_name'));
```

which returns an array of all country ids.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN,0)
    ->select("mycolumn")
    ->from(MyModel::model()->tableSchema->name)
    ->queryAll();
```

The result would be:

```
array('foo', 'bar', 'lala')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Yii2 ArrayHelper by including to your controller this will convert a model data to an associated array

```
    use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper; 

    $post = ArrayHelper::toArray(ClientProfilesForm::findOne(['id' => 1]));

//or use it directly by 

    $post = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::toArray(ClientProfilesForm::findOne(['id' => 1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Model::find()->select('id')->column();
```

Will return array of IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Use Chtml to this is a Ugly Hack! Apply this solution is the better way to this that I found:

```
public function queryAll($condition = '', $params = array())
{
    $criteria = $this->getCommandBuilder()->createCriteria($condition, $params);
    $this->applyScopes($criteria);
    $command = $this->getCommandBuilder()->createFindCommand($this->getTableSchema(), $criteria);
    $results = $command->queryAll();
    return $results;
}
```

You can add this code to an ActiveRecord class, e.g.:

```
class ActiveRecord extends CActiveRecord {
//...
}
```

And, use this way:

```
return $model->queryAll($criteria);
```

You can read more about in [this link](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/531).

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Yii1.1 and you need to get ALL data from AR as array you need to care about that it self. Yii1.1 AR doesn't have this feature out of the box

In Yii2 AR has [asArray()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait.html#asArray()-detail) method, it's very helpful

I hope my answer helps someone

Comment: Providing an example may help a little better.