# How can I recieve array using Yii ActiveRecord

Tags: arrays, activerecord, yii

Consider this query and its result:

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand(
    "SELECT name FROM users WHERE city='Paris'"
)->queryColumn();
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => John Kerry
    [1] => Marry White
    [2] => Mike Jain
)
```

Any suggestions on how to build this query with `ActiveRecord`?
It is necessary to receive the **array**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yii - How to get a values array from an Active Record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377024/yii-how-to-get-a-values-array-from-an-active-record)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Duplicate:
[Yii - How to get a values array from an Active Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377024/yii-how-to-get-a-values-array-from-an-active-record/)

use `CHtml::listData` (see http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/48/by-example-chtml/#hh3 )

```
$users = User::model()->findAll();
$usersArr = CHtml::listData( $users, 'id' , 'city');
print_r( $usersArr );
```

It will give you array id => city

```
Array {
    2 => 'Paris',
    102 => 'Riga',
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Kludge! See the answer of @Telvin Nguyen. But better is use an anonymous function to extract result from findAll as a array.

Answer (score 1):

An active record, by it's name, will return a whole record for each row in your database, so the best way to obtain just one field from each row would be using the [querybuilder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder) with something like what you've got above.

If you really wanted to use AR and just want the name in an array then something like this might work:

```
$names = array();
$users = users::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('city'=>'Paris'));
foreach(array_keys($users) as $key)
{
    $names[] = $users[$key]->name;
}
```

Although that's a lot of overhead to pull just the name if you're not using any other details from the AR search.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have dealt with the same problem, I would like to use the ActiveRecord instead of CDBCommand. I have answered on the similar question before

[get array from active record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235249/yii-find-query-result-without-table-structure?answertab=active#tab-top)

```
$words = Word::model()->findAll();
$data=array_map(create_function('$m','return $m->getAttributes();'),$words);
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: doesn't ActiveRecord return objects? `array_map` expects parameter 2 to be an array - but since $words is an object, we get an error. (?)

Comment: @Steven CActiveRecord comprises the findall method return the array of records found. An empty array is returned if none is found. In my example, the $words variable always be an array.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you can use [findAllByAttributes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAllByAttributes-detail)(array $attributes, mixed $condition='', array $params=array ( )) and also tell this method to fetch only the 'name' column for the records it matches. To do this, you'll need to pass as $condition an instance of [CDbCriteria](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria) and specify on this instance the 'select' columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use Chtml to this is a Ugly Hack! In short, you can do this:

```
public function queryAll($condition = '', $params = array())
{
    $criteria = $this->getCommandBuilder()->createCriteria($condition, $params);
    $this->applyScopes($criteria);
    $command = $this->getCommandBuilder()->createFindCommand($this->getTableSchema(), $criteria);
    $results = $command->queryAll();
    return $results;
}
```

Follow my answer to a identical problem in other question, in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377024/yii-how-to-get-a-values-array-from-an-active-record/20546540#20546540).